# Minimum Number of move to reach End

Tags: java, arrays, minimum

I need to calculate the minimum number of jumps to reach the end of an Array with dice throw Array Value may be negative/positive value:

- when positive----> Move Forward
- when negative ------> go back

The Array may also contain R value, which means that the player have to throw the dice again

The start position is marked on our Array with S and End position with E The Start Position is not always the first element of the Array and End position is not always at the end, it can even be before S

Example: Array = {4, S, -2,1, R, 4,3,4,3,-5,2,-4, E}

the player start on S position the fastest way to reach E:

- Throwing the dice to have 3 and reach the R case (first move)
- throwing the dice again and having 6 to reach the 2 Case (second movement)
- Jumping 2 cases to reach E (third move)

so the best solution for this example is: 3 moves

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to have an algorithm question with no code. If you have a solution you are working on, then please include it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, "just providing the algorithm" still translates to: "please do the core part of my homework for me". That is not how SO works. You are supposed to work on the problem yourself and show that to us. We **help** you solving your problem; but most of the time, nobody is willing to **do** your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets give you a hint: the key thing to learn here: sometimes you have to transform your input data in order to find a good way to solve your problem.

In your case; consider turning your array into a graph:

- Each array index is a node within that graph
- The value of each array position tells you something about edges to other nodes. For example, if a(0) is R; then a(0) would be connected to a(1), a(2) .. a(6) - because you can reach the next 6 elements.

For starters; I would suggest to do that manually; just draw the graph for example array.

So, the steps to solve your problem:

1. Transform your array into a graph
2. Search the net for algorithms to find minimum length paths in graphs
3. Print out that path; resulting in the minimal list from S to E

Implementation is left as exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you i'm working on a solution but  how to implemant the case where after x jump it bring me back to the first node ? it give me infinit loop

Comment: As I told you: the underlying data structure is directed graph that can contain cycles. That means: your algorithm that searches for the shortest path between nodes E and S needs to **remember** which nodes where already visited for the current path. To avoid the endless recursion that you are now faced with. In your case: remember the indexes that were already visited.

Comment: Thanx for the tip , i used a boolean array to mark visited node and it works      i shared the solution

Comment: Good thing to post your solution; but side note: you might want to read about java coding style conventions; as you are violating some of them (for example variable names start with lowercase letters). Then I would encourage to check out "Clean code" by Robert Martin. As your code might be working, but its structure isn't very good. It starts with messy formatting. Any IDE allows you to auto-format your code, that alone makes it easier to read. Which makes it hard for anybody to read; for example to figure why you run out of heap space running it on large input.

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote this working solution i share it for anyone interested , but when it comes to deal with big Array (3000 for example) it throws a java heap space error as the code will consume huge amount of memory , any help or advice will be appreciated**

```
public class Solution {
static int startPosition;


public static int compute(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    final int totalNodeCount = getTotalNodeNumber(br);
    final String caseArray[] = new String[totalNodeCount];
    bufferToArray(br, caseArray);
    startPosition = getStartPosition(caseArray);
    final boolean visited[] = new boolean[caseArray.length];
    int minimumNumberOfMove = 0;
    final List<Integer> reachableList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
    {
        visitedInitilise(visited);
        if (((startPosition + i) < totalNodeCount) && ((startPosition + i) > 0))
            getMinimumNumberOfMoves(caseArray, visited, startPosition + i, 0, reachableList);
    }

    // Retriving Minimum number of move from all reachble route
    if (reachableList.isEmpty())
        minimumNumberOfMove = Constants.IMPOSSIBLE;
    else

    {
        minimumNumberOfMove = reachableList.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < reachableList.size(); i++)
            if (reachableList.get(i) < minimumNumberOfMove)
                minimumNumberOfMove = reachableList.get(i);

    }

    return minimumNumberOfMove;

}


static int getStartPosition(String[] plateau){

    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (plateau.length - 1); i++)
        if (plateau[i].equals("S")) 
        {
            startIndex = i;
            break;
        }

    return startIndex;
}
static void bufferToArray(BufferedReader br, String[] plateau) {
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    try 
    {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            plateau[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


static int getTotalNodeNumber(BufferedReader br) {
    int i = 0;
    try 
    {
        i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return i;
}
static List<Integer> getMinimumNumberOfMoves(String[] plateau, boolean[] visited, final int currentIndex,
        int currentNumberOfMoves, List<Integer> list) {

    Boolean endIsReached = false;
    Boolean impossible = false;
    visited[startPosition] = true;
    // Checking if the current index index is negativ
    if (currentIndex < 0)
        impossible = true;

    while ((endIsReached == false) && (impossible == false) && (visited[currentIndex] == false)
            && (currentIndex < plateau.length)) 
    {
        try 
        {

            switch (plateau[currentIndex]) {
            case "E": {
                // if end is reached , pushing number of move into our list
                endIsReached = true;
                list.add(currentNumberOfMoves + 1);
                break;

            }

            case "R": {
                // Marking node as visited
                visited[currentIndex] = true;

                for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
                {
                    // Marking all case after R case as non visited
                    for (int j = currentIndex + 1; j < visited.length; j++)
                        visited[j] = false;
                    // Calculating number of move after R case
                    if (((currentIndex + i) < plateau.length) && (currentIndex > 0))
                        getMinimumNumberOfMoves(plateau, visited, currentIndex + i, currentNumberOfMoves + 1, list);
                }

                break;
            }
            default: {
                // Cheking if node was already visited
                if (visited[currentIndex] == true) 
                {
                    // Marking all node as non visited
                    visitedInitilise(visited);

                    impossible = true;
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // when the node was not visited before , catch the jump
                    // value
                    int jumpValue = Integer.parseInt(plateau[currentIndex]);
                    // cheking that the next node is not bigger than node
                    // number and not negativ
                    if (((currentIndex + jumpValue) > plateau.length) || (currentIndex < 0)) 
                    {
                        impossible = true;
                        break;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        // Marking node as visited
                        visited[currentIndex] = true;
                        // calculating minimum number of move starting from
                        // this node
                        getMinimumNumberOfMoves(plateau, visited, currentIndex + jumpValue,
                                currentNumberOfMoves + 1, list);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            }

        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
    }
    if (impossible == true)
        currentNumberOfMoves = 0;

    return list;

}

static void visitedInitilise(boolean visited[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= (visited.length - 1); i++)
            visited[i] = false;
    }

public static void main(String args[]){
    String testCaseID = "15"; // Write a test file number from 1 to 15, or
                                // ALL
    TestCases.test(testCaseID);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is written in a very-hard-to-read-way. Don't expect too many folks being interested in spending time on analyzing input like this ... but you might want to put your code on codereview.stackexchange.com; and get some feedback from there.